# Agregar a una lista la misma lista con append

Tags: python

Jugando un poco con la terminal de python me dio por agregarle a un lista la misma lista

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.append(a)
```

Yo esperaba la siguiente salida

> [1, 2, 3, [1,2,3]]

Algo asi como hacer un `i += i`.
Pero el resultado arrojado fue el siguiente

> [1, 2, 3, [...]]

Mi duda no es como agregar la lista a si misma, si no el porque pasa eso, que significan los tres puntos que agrega a la lista, entiendo un poco como funcionan las referencias en python, pero creo que no del todo porque esto no le encuentro logica, espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que lo entiendas mejor, unos dibujos.

En python todo son referencias (puedes entenderlo como apuntadores). La variable `a` es una referencia a una zona de la memoria donde hay una lista, que no es más que otra colección de referencias llamadas `a[0]`, `a[1]`, etc.

Cuando inicializas `a` así:

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

las referencias dentro de la lista "apuntan" a los correspondientes datos, que son los números 1, 2, 3, etc...

La situación es la de esta figura:

[image: Lista inicial]

Después haces:

```
a.append(a)
```

Lo que crea un nuevo elemento `a[3]`, que es otra referencia, pero en esta ocasión, el dato a que apunta es la propia lista `a`. Es decir, es una referencia *circular* como muestra la figura siguiente:

[image: referencia circular]

Si te fijas, al tratar de imprimir esta lista elemento a elemento, los tres primeros no dan ningún problema, y la cosa comenzaría así `[1, 2, 3`, pero al llegar al cuarto elemento se encuentra con que es una sub-lista (de hecho ella misma), por lo que deberá abrir corchete y mostrar el contenido de esa lista. De nuevo en esta sub-lista no hay problema en los primeros tres elementos, y veríamos `[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3`, pero al llegar al cuarto se encuentra que es otra sub-lista (otra vez ella misma) por lo que de nuevo abrirá corchetes para mostrar sus elementos, y veríamos: `[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3`

Ya te imaginas a dónde va a parar esto. Cada vez que llega al cuarto elemento y ve que es una sublista, intenta imprimirla y eso no termina nunca por culpa de la referencia circular. En cierta forma es como un *bucle infinito en los datos*.

Por suerte `print()` es lo bastante listo como para detectar esa circularidad y abreviar la salida como `[...]`. De lo contrario se pondría a imprimir la secuencia `[1, 2, 3, [` una y otra vez como loco, sin terminar nunca y sin llegar a cerrar los corchetes.

Esto es muy diferente a lo que obtendrías si guardaras en `a[3]` una *copia* de lo que había en `a` (en lugar de una referencia), pues en este caso se crea una nueva lista (la copiada), y esa copia no contiene la referencia circular. Es decir, al hacer:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.append(a[:])
```

la situación es ahora:

[image: Con copia]

Aunque la figura es un tanto confusa debido a que los elementos de la segunda lista son referencias *a los mismos datos* que contenía la primera, la lista añadida a `a` en cambio ahora es otra, y ya no es una referencia a sí misma. Por tanto ahora al imprimir `a` no hay problema alguno. Tras los tres primeros elementos `[1, 2, 3` el cuarto es una lista con tres elementos, de nuevo `[1, 2, 3]` pero no hay en ella ningún cuarto elemento que se refiera circularmente a sí misma, por lo que no hay "bucle infinito", y simplemente se mostraría  `[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, yo pensaba que python al referenciar a un objeto en este caso `a`, hacia referencia a los elementos de esa referencia, dando como resultado el segundo ejemplo, pero es bueno saber que referencia directamente a `a`, supongo entonce que para referenciar a los elementos de esa referencia se usaria `*a`  verdad?. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Los tres puntos son simplemente la forma de mostrar el contenido que tiene python por consola. Realmente lo que tienes en la posición 3 es una referencia a la misma lista, si en consola escribes a[3] obtendrás de nuevo [1, 2, 3, [...]], si escribes a[3][3] lo mismo, porque al acceder a "a[3]" en realidad estás volviendo a acceder a la variable "a".

Comment: Gracias por responder, entiendo esa parte, pero porque ese comportamiento, porque agrega la lista asi, porque pareciera que la agrega infinitamente?

Answer (score 1):

Esto `[...]` no es más que la forma en que python representa que el elemento en cuestión es una referencia a sí mismo. En tu caso, lo que tienes es una lista que tiene un último elemento que es la referencia a la propia lista. Es la forma de escapar a una representación habitual que provocaría una recursión infinita si se siguiera ese mismo modelo.

Si iteramos e imprimimos los elementos:

```
a = [1,2,3]
a.append(a)

for i, e in enumerate(a, 1):
  print("El elemento {0} de la lista a es: {1}".format(i, e))


El elemento 1 de la lista a es: 1
El elemento 2 de la lista a es: 2
El elemento 3 de la lista a es: 3
El elemento 4 de la lista a es: [1, 2, 3, [...]]
```

Tu lista conceptualmente es así `[número, número, número, referencia]` la representación es `[1, 2, 3, [...]]`, ahora si vas a imprimir el cuarto elemento, `python` te mostrará el objeto al que apunta la `referencia` es decir `[1, 2, 3, [...]]` y así `ad infinitum`

Por cierto, y por las dudas, para hacer lo que esperabas inicialmente, debes agregar una copia de la lista en vez de la referencia a sí misma:

```
a.append(list(a))
```

o bien

```
a.append(a[:])
```